# Actionbars not setting on first 2 children of a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-recyclerview

I am trying to make an app which shows list of Orders in a RecyclerView.
Each Order has its own toolbar (with actionbar attached to it) but whenever I start that activity the first 2 Orders do not attach the actionbar to the toolbar...
Following are some of my code snippets:

onBindViewHolder cod -

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    // - get element from your dataset at this position
    // - replace the contents of the view with that element
    String customer_name=mDataset[position].getCustomer().getFirstName()+" "+mDataset[position].getCustomer().getLastName();
    String customer_phone=mDataset[position].getCustomer().getPhone()+"";
    //Dates
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    //
    String date=sdf.format(mDataset[position].getBookingDate() );
    String booking_date="Booking Date\n"+date;
    //
    date=sdf.format(mDataset[position].getPickUpDate());
    String pickup_date="Pick Up Date\n"+date;
    //
    date=sdf.format(mDataset[position].getDropDate());
    String drop_date="Drop Date\n"+date;
    holder.order_id_oh.setText(mDataset[position].getOrderCode());
    holder.booking_date_oh.setText(booking_date);
    holder.pickup_date_oh.setText(pickup_date);
    holder.order_status_oh.setText(mDataset[position].getStatus().toString());
    holder.drop_date_oh.setText(drop_date);
    holder.customer_name_oh.setText(customer_name);
    holder.phone_no_oh.setText(customer_phone);
    holder.pickup_locaion_oh.setText(mDataset[position].getAddress());
    holder.drop_location_oh.setText(mDataset[position].getCustomer().getAddress());
    //
    //
    ((AppCompatActivity)orderAdapter_ctx).setSupportActionBar(holder.menu_toolbar_oh);
    //
    holder.phone_no_oh.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#845a9a"));

    //

}
```

Parameterized Constructor for getting Context -

```
public OrderAdapter(Order[] myDataset,Context ctx) {
    orderAdapter_ctx=ctx;
    mDataset = myDataset;
}
```

Part of the Activity related to Recycler -

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_order_history);
    //
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view_order_history);

    // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
    // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    // use a linear layout manager
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mAdapter = new OrderAdapter(orders,this);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Here are 2 screenshots:

[First 2 Orders don't have the actionbar attached (3 dots are missing)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXNWT.jpg)

[Here the actionbar is attached (3 dots are present)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scAuw.jpg)

Please help me with this...

Comment: Do you need to have toolbars there? Why not just create a layout for each item with the 3 dots to the right?

Comment: Yes I need those toolbars! Because I have to add further buttons on them. By: Creating a layout for each item, you mean that I should make a new layout file of an Order and include it into the Recycler?

Comment: Yeah you can create a common layout then reuse it! Then for the drop-down optionsMenu, just use a popupwindow